# Retornar uma string em C

Tags: c, funções

Bom dia,quero retornar uma palavra que esta em um arquivo,porem ta printando uns caracteres estranhos,segue o codigo.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>

int *abrir_arquivo(){
     //o cursor ira percorrer as letras do arquivo
    int cursor,i;
   // Reserva memória que não será desalocada, para armazenar 20 chars
    char *palavra = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

    //O arquivo de palavras que sera lido
    FILE *file;
    //abrindo o arquivo
    file=fopen("Frutas forca.txt", "r");
    //se o arquivo for encontrado
    i=0;
    //Vendo se o arquivo foi encontrado
    if(file){
        //o cursor ira pegar cada caractere do arquivo e adicionar na variavel palavra
        while((cursor=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
            palavra[i]=cursor;
            i++;
        }
         // Adiciono um "null terminator", em C ele é interpretado como fim da string
        palavra[i]= '\0';

    //MOstrando o conteudo do arquivo
    printf("%s",palavra);
        //fecha o arquivo
        fclose(file);

    }

return palavra;
}


int main()
{

    char *palavraforca;

    *palavraforca=abrir_arquivo();
    printf("%s",palavraforca);













    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir retornar uma string dessa forma em C, existem alguns conceitos que você deveria entender para realizar o que está tentando fazer.

Uma string é apenas um array de bytes.

A variável `palavra` não armazena a string inteira, mas sim um ponteiro apontando para o início do array de bytes.

Como você declara sua string como `char palavra[20]`, a memória para armazenar esse array será reservada no `stack`/`pilha`.

Essa área da memória é desalocada quando a função termina.

Isso significa que se você retornar um ponteiro para essa área da memória, ele será inválido, pois a memória foi desalocada. Para poder retornar uma string, ou melhor, um ponteiro para onde começa sua string, você precisa aloca-la em uma região da memória que não será desalocada automaticamente no término da função. Utilize o `malloc` para isso:

```
// O retorno é do tipo char*, um ponteiro
char *abrir_arquivo() {
     // O cursor irá percorrer as letras do arquivo
    int cursor, i;
    // Reserva memória que não será desalocada, para armazenar 20 chars
    char *palavra = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

    // O arquivo de palavras que sera lido
    FILE *file;
    // Abrindo o arquivo
    file = fopen("Frutas forca.txt", "r");
    // Se o arquivo for encontrado
    i = 0;
    // Vendo se o arquivo foi encontrado
    if (file) {
        // O cursor ira pegar cada caractere do arquivo e adicionar na variável palavra
        while ((cursor = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            palavra[i] = cursor;
            i++;
        }
        // Adiciono um "null terminator", em C ele é interpretado como fim da string
        palavra[i] = '\0';
        // Mostrando o conteudo do arquivo
        printf("%s", palavra);
        // Fecha o arquivo
        fclose(file);

    }

    return palavra;
}
```

Comment: mas como vou retornar na main?tipo:main(){palavraforca=função?

Comment: Da mesma forma que você retorna qualquer outro valor: `char *palavraforca = abrir_arquivo();`

Comment: mudei,e n deu certo,editei o código com suas sugestões,ele continua so printando na função,na main ela nao printa

Comment: @Lolzeiro, você fez errado. Se for declarar `char *palavraforca;` em uma linha, e então a iniciar em outra linha, deveria utilizar `palavraforca = abrir_arquivo();` sem asterisco.

Comment: vlw sio,deu certo aqui kkk,tava desde cedo querendo fazer,muito obrigado!!

Comment: Um detalhe importante é que não necessariamente é preciso usar alocação dinâmica nesse caso, em que sabe-se o tamanho da string em tempo de compilação. Uma possibilidade é, por exemplo, declarar a função como `void abrir_arquivo(char palavra[], int tamanho)`, delegando a alocação do array de chars para o chamador da função. Ele pode, então, escolher se vai alocar estaticamente (pilha) ou dinamicamente.